Debug minted error when there are many files
There are many \inputminted in my document. If get an error:
[1] (./_minted-acwj_chapters_1-2/default.pygstyle)
(./_minted-acwj_chapters_1-2/C5B1981F0EFA52D3BED4B9EF6D07C800D00D33EC522907285B
7123A6F8EB8958.pygtex
Missing character: There is no ^^89 (U+0089) in font SauceCodePro NFM/OT:script
=latn;language=dflt;!
Missing character: There is no ^^89 (U+0089) in font SauceCodePro NFM/OT:script
=latn;language=dflt;!
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.3 ^^Z

?

How do I know which file passed to \inputminted caused the error?
EDIT:
If I only had this document, I know I could manually find the guilty by gradually deleting calls to \inputminted.
However, I need this because I'm creating a tool (open source) that automatically dumps the contents of all files in a directory.
It would be nice for the users if they know which file to delete when they encounter an error (probally because it is a binary file)
EDIT2:
Here is a minimal (not) working example.
The drawback is that it depends on files (it should work on a Debian distro)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{minted}
\begin{document}

\newpage
\section*{/etc/hosts}
\inputminted[]{text}{/etc/hosts}

\newpage
\section*{/bin/ls}
\inputminted[]{text}{/bin/ls} % <- this is the guilty

\newpage
\section*{/etc/passwd}
\inputminted[]{text}{/etc/passwd}
\end{document}

$ pdflatex -shell-escape MnotWE.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MnotWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2023-06-05>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/catchfile/catchfile.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty) (./MnotWE.w18))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))/home/isidro/mp/code_to_pdf/venv/bin/pygmentize

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file MnotWE.aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (./_minted-MnotWE/default.pygstyle)
(./_minted-MnotWE/13B646BEF64E540BF4911AB7B9EF88671D183D6FFFBC5FCFF1FBFEA5155AC
373.pygtex) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./_minted-MnotWE/BAD51FDC96211E5A54846CDFCD70C3A605664793AF85DE280160029970BAE
957.pygtex
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.2 ^^?
       ELF\PYGZcb{}\PYGZob{}\PYGZob{}\PYGZbs{}\PYGZbs{}\PYGZbs{}\PYGZbs{}\PY...

? help
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
Continue, and I'll forget that it ever happened.

? help
Sorry, I already gave what help I could...
Maybe you should try asking a human?
An error might have occurred before I noticed any problems.
``If all else fails, read the instructions.''

?
! Emergency stop.
l.2

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on MnotWE.log.


you are on page 2 of your document, it shouldn't be so difficult for you to identify the problematic file.

Thanks for commenting @UlrikeFischer! edited question to clarify

Give us a M(not)WE.

Look into the intermediate minted file. While it will show a ton of highlighting instructions, the original source code is still interspersed between them and it should give you enough clues to identify the file.

Added M(not)WE @projetmbc

Hi @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that is difficult if it is a binary file. You could know its magic number, but it doesn't always help. In the example I added, you can see a ELF which is a clue.

With an up-to-date minted, your example would give you the error ! Package minted Error:   => ./document:7: Cannot decode file "/bin/ls" with encoding="utf8".

(and with previous minted versions, which required shell-escape, I wouldn't include code you haven't examined yourself)

That looks nice! I will try with a newer minted @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

An up-to-date texlive 2024 will include the new minted version.

You can get texlive 2024 from tug.org

I feel like I must be missing something here, but why are trying to typeset a binary file? as @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz says, you will get an error. but, error or not, it makes no sense to typeset a binary? moreover, it is not a good idea at all, imho, to input a binary. it is like cat /bin/ls or something - at best, it will spew gibberish. (but usually, it is a bit more disruptive than that.)


If I only had this document, I know I could manually find the guilty by gradually deleting calls to \inputminted. However, I need this because I'm creating a tool (open source) that automatically dumps the contents of all files in a directory. It would be nice for the users if they know which file to delete when they encounter an error (probally because it is a binary file)

Please, do not do this. Feeding arbitrary content to TeX is worse than a bad idea. It is, IMHO, a truly terrible idea.
It is an even worse idea if you run with shell escape, as you are currently doing:

\write18 enabled.

But restricted shell escape is nothing like a sufficient safeguard.
If you really want to develop a tool of this kind, you should ensure the tool checks the nature of the input before feeding it to TeX. That is, you should pro-actively distinguish at least some kinds of content.
I don't have in mind rendering it safe for arbitrary content, but it should at least filter out anything which is not plain text with a suitable encoding.
It's not unreasonable to assume no nefarious input - that's pretty much assumed by most TeX processing.
Given that assumption, it should be relatively straightforward to select only files meeting those criteria and to refuse to typeset anything else1.
1Or refuse unless users enable some option to force the issue, if you really think there's some legitimate use-case for typesetting binaries.

Thank you for the extended response @cfr.
I am not trying to typeset binaries.
I can explain better with an example. Imagine that you want to study this repo https://github.com/DoctorWkt/acwj and want to print it.
If you use my tool, the resulting document will contain a \inputminted[]{text}{00_Introduction/Figs/parsing_steps.png} and will fail if you try to generate the pdf.

I could easily filter binary files since it is written in Python, but I think that is the user's job.
Knowing that the -shell-escape is dangerous, I could warn users not run against untrusted repositories (or execute it inside a container).
